# Como "chamar" uma função de uma tabela de Lua em C++

Tags: c++, lua, scripting

Eu estou tentando "chamar" uma função de uma `table` escrito em `Lua`. O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo passar três argumentos a esta função.

Quando eu passo os argumentos, é como se a `Lua` pulasse o primeiro argumento e continuasse do segundo em diante. A baixo um trecho do código.

```cpp
// C++
// Função responsável por chamar a função do script
int CPP_get(lua_State* ls)
{
    lua_getfield(ls, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "vec"); // Coloca vec na pilha
    lua_getfield(ls, -1, "func"); // coloca a função func na pilha
    lua_remove(ls, -2); // Remove vec da pilha
    dumpStack(ls); // Mostra a pilha

    lua_pushnumber(ls, 2.0f); // Primeiro argumento
    lua_pushnumber(ls, 4.0f); // Segundo argumento
    lua_pushnumber(ls, 8.0f); // Terceiro argumento

    dumpStack(ls); // Mostra a pilha
    std::cout << "\n";

    lua_pcall(ls, 3, 1, 0); // Chama a função

    return 1;
}
```

```lua
-- Lua
-- Table
vec = {}
vec.__index = vec

-- Função a ser chamada
function vec:func(x, y, z)
    print("vec:func:", x, y, z)
    return "return: OK"
end

-- Chamando a função
print("CPP.get:", CPP.get())
```

A função `dumpStack`, é para mostrar os elementos da "pilha" atual. Abaixo um print de como fica a "pilha". No final da execução ele só passa do segundo argumento em diante.

[image: Imagen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sua função na verdade tem 4 argumentos. O código

```lua
function vec:func(x, y, z)
  print("vec:func:", x, y, z)
  return "return: OK"
end
```

é açúcar sintático para

```lua
vec.func = function(self, x, y, z)
  print("vec:func:", x, y, z)
  return "return: OK"
end
```

---

Tem duas coisas que você pode fazer: se sua função não precisa do self, você pode fazer ela receber só 3 argumentos mesmo:

```lua
vec.func = function(x, y, z) ... end
-- OU
function vec.func(x,y,z) ... end
```

alternativamente, você pode fazer o seu código C++ passar `vec` como o primeiro argumento da função. No seu caso, vc pode fazer isso trocando as posições de vec e func na pilha ao invés de remover vec.

```cpp
// C++
// Função responsável por chamar a função do script
int CPP_get(lua_State* ls)
{
    lua_getfield(ls, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "vec"); // Coloca vec na pilha
    lua_getfield(ls, -1, "func"); // coloca a função func na pilha

    lua_insert(L, -2);        // Troca os dois elementos no topo da pilha de posição
    lua_pushnumber(ls, 2.0f); // Primeiro argumento  (segundo, contando com o self)
    lua_pushnumber(ls, 4.0f); // Segundo argumento   (terceiro, contando com o self)
    lua_pushnumber(ls, 8.0f); // Terceiro argumento  (quarto, contando com o self)

    lua_pcall(ls, 4, 1, 0); // Chama a função  //4 argumentos!

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ^^, é semelhante a Python. Mas fiquei com outra dúvida. Você sabe me dizer se existe alguma diferença entre `.` ou `:` ?. Tem como fazer com que o "programador" utilize somente um método?. Eu uso `.` em módulos, e `:` em métodos de tabelas/"classes" (Na minha opinião fica mais organizado).

Comment: A diferença de Lua e Python é que só existem funções e o `:` é 100% açúcar sintático (vc pode ler mais detalhes no manual ou no programmiing in lua). Se vc quiser vc pode traduzir todos os `:` pra `.`, mas as chamadas de método passam a ficar bem chatinhas de escrever (`obj.method(obj, 17)` vs `obj:method(17)`). Quanto à uma recomendção, use métodos com self para métodos de instância e funções sem self para métodos estáticos da sua classe.

Comment: Açúcar sintático? o que é isso?

Comment: Açúcar sintático é uma o nome que usamos para descrever uma funcionalidade da linguagem de programação pode ser vista como apenas uma abreviação. Todo programa usando o açúcar pode ser reescrito usando apenas operações mais básicas. Por exemplo, na linguagem C o operador += pode ser visto como um açúcar sintático. Todo uso de `a += b` pode ser reescrito como `a = a + b`.